# How to avoid [Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy'] error?

Tags: spring, maven, svn, jdbc, log4j2

I'd checkout the web-project(Spring framework) from my company's svn.

When I run it on tomcat server, It was ok.

But I tried to log-in at webpage from project, the error log of below has occurred.

It seems error because of kinds of log4j2 jars, but I checked the maven dependency, and the jar file is already downloaded.

I checked the compiler compiliance level also, it was 1.7.

I delete the project and re-checkout from our svn over and over.

What's wrong about this??

at POM.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>1.16</version>
        </dependency>
```

below is log.

```
2015-03-16 18:15:24,354 ERROR [log4jdbc.log4j2] null. DataSource.getConnection()
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy' for connect URL 'jdbc:log4jdbc:edb://218.145.26.12:5445/dementia'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DataSourceSpy.getConnection(DataSourceSpy.java:147) [log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4-1.16.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:224) [spring-jdbc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.prepareStatement(SqlExecutor.java:497) [ibatis-sqlmap-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.executeQuery(SqlExecutor.java:175) [ibatis-sqlmap-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.sqlExecuteQuery(MappedStatement.java:221) [ibatis-sqlmap-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(MappedStatement.java:189) [ibatis-sqlmap-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryForObject(MappedStatement.java:120) [ibatis-sqlmap-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:518) [ibatis-sqlmap-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:493) [ibatis-sqlmap-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForObject(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:106) [ibatis-sqlmap-2.3.4.726.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$1.doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:273) [spring-orm-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:203) [spring-orm-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForObject(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:271) [spring-orm-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at dementia.casestudy.login.dao.CaseLoginDAO.getLoginUserCountMac(CaseLoginDAO.java:22) [CaseLoginDAO.class:?]
    at dementia.casestudy.login.service.CaseLoginService.getLoginUserCountMac(CaseLoginService.java:30) [CaseLoginService.class:?]
    at dementia.casestudy.login.controller.CaseLoginController.loginProc(CaseLoginController.java:74) [CaseLoginController.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176) [spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at dementia.casestudy.common.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:456) [AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.class:?]
    at dementia.casestudy.common.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426) [AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.class:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106) [spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    ... 50 more
[http-8080-7] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
[http-8080-7] INFO org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
2015-03-16 18:15:24,444 ERROR [log4jdbc.log4j2] null. DataSource.getConnection()
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy' for connect URL 'jdbc:log4jdbc:edb://218.145.26.12:5445/dementia'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DataSourceSpy.getConnection(DataSourceSpy.java:147) [log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4-1.16.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:224) [spring-jdbc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.getMetaData(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:285) [spring-jdbc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:320) [spring-jdbc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:214) [spring-jdbc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:140) [spring-jdbc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:103) [spring-jdbc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99) [spring-jdbc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:206) [spring-orm-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForObject(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:271) [spring-orm-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at dementia.casestudy.login.dao.CaseLoginDAO.getLoginUserCountMac(CaseLoginDAO.java:22) [CaseLoginDAO.class:?]
    at dementia.casestudy.login.service.CaseLoginService.getLoginUserCountMac(CaseLoginService.java:30) [CaseLoginService.class:?]
    at dementia.casestudy.login.controller.CaseLoginController.loginProc(CaseLoginController.java:74) [CaseLoginController.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176) [spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at dementia.casestudy.common.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:456) [AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.class:?]
    at dementia.casestudy.common.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426) [AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.class:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106) [spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    ... 47 more
[http-8080-7] WARN org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory - Error while extracting database product name - falling back to empty error codes
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy' for connect URL 'jdbc:log4jdbc:edb://218.145.26.12:5445/dementia'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:296)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:320)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:214)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:140)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForObject(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:271)
    at dementia.casestudy.login.dao.CaseLoginDAO.getLoginUserCountMac(CaseLoginDAO.java:22)
    at dementia.casestudy.login.service.CaseLoginService.getLoginUserCountMac(CaseLoginService.java:30)
    at dementia.casestudy.login.controller.CaseLoginController.loginProc(CaseLoginController.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at dementia.casestudy.common.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:456)
    at dementia.casestudy.common.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy' for connect URL 'jdbc:log4jdbc:edb://218.145.26.12:5445/dementia'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DataSourceSpy.getConnection(DataSourceSpy.java:147)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:224)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:285)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    ... 47 more
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: SqlMapClient operation; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [null]; error code [0];   
--- The error occurred in egovframework/sqlmap/case/login/CaseLogin_Postgres.xml.  
--- The error occurred while executing query.  
--- Check the    SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TB_MAC    WHERE     PLACE IN (SELECT ADMIN_PLACE FROM TB_MEMBER_ADMIN      WHERE ADMIN_ID = ?     AND admin_value  = 'Y'      AND admin_level != '0')     AND log_YN       = 'Y'      AND mac_addr     = ?  .  
--- Check the SQL Statement (preparation failed).  
--- Cause: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy' for connect URL 'jdbc:log4jdbc:edb://218.145.26.12:5445/dementia'; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in egovframework/sqlmap/case/login/CaseLogin_Postgres.xml.  
--- The error occurred while executing query.  
--- Check the    SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TB_MAC    WHERE     PLACE IN (SELECT ADMIN_PLACE FROM TB_MEMBER_ADMIN      WHERE ADMIN_ID = ?     AND admin_value  = 'Y'      AND admin_level != '0')     AND log_YN       = 'Y'      AND mac_addr     = ?  .  
--- Check the SQL Statement (preparation failed).  
--- Cause: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy' for connect URL 'jdbc:log4jdbc:edb://218.145.26.12:5445/dementia'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForObject(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:271)
    at dementia.casestudy.login.dao.CaseLoginDAO.getLoginUserCountMac(CaseLoginDAO.java:22)
    at dementia.casestudy.login.service.CaseLoginService.getLoginUserCountMac(CaseLoginService.java:30)
    at dementia.casestudy.login.controller.CaseLoginController.loginProc(CaseLoginController.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at dementia.casestudy.common.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:456)
    at dementia.casestudy.common.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in egovframework/sqlmap/case/login/CaseLogin_Postgres.xml.  
--- The error occurred while executing query.  
--- Check the    SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TB_MAC    WHERE     PLACE IN (SELECT ADMIN_PLACE FROM TB_MEMBER_ADMIN      WHERE ADMIN_ID = ?     AND admin_value  = 'Y'      AND admin_level != '0')     AND log_YN       = 'Y'      AND mac_addr     = ?  .  
--- Check the SQL Statement (preparation failed).  
--- Cause: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy' for connect URL 'jdbc:log4jdbc:edb://218.145.26.12:5445/dementia'
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(MappedStatement.java:201)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryForObject(MappedStatement.java:120)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:518)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:493)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForObject(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:106)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$1.doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:203)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy' for connect URL 'jdbc:log4jdbc:edb://218.145.26.12:5445/dementia'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DataSourceSpy.getConnection(DataSourceSpy.java:147)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:224)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.prepareStatement(SqlExecutor.java:497)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.executeQuery(SqlExecutor.java:175)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.sqlExecuteQuery(MappedStatement.java:221)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(MappedStatement.java:189)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    ... 50 more
```

Comment: Ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that either the class `net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy` is not in the classpath (you can verify this by calling `Class.forName("net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy")` somewhere early in your app and seeing if this causes an exception), or this class returns `false` when `"jdbc:log4jdbc:edb://218.145.26.12:5445/dementia"` is passed to its [acceptsURL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html#acceptsURL(java.lang.String)) method. The latter could be caused by a misspelled URL.

Or it could be because datasources are [not supported yet](https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/wiki/FAQ) by log4jdbc...

Comment: log4jdbc-log4j2 fork in question does support datasources: http://log4jdbc.brunorozendo.com/

Answer (score 1):

In my case it kept throwing undetailed

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy
      at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
      at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:283)
      at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:171)
```

until I added `log4jdbc.log4j2.properties` file to classpath with

```
log4jdbc.spylogdelegator.name=net.sf.log4jdbc.log.slf4j.Slf4jSpyLogDelegator
```

It seems log4jdbc-log4j2 requires this file in case log4j2 is not present on classpath.

See the docs at http://log4jdbc.brunorozendo.com.

Answer (score -1):

please use the following Driver class name

**net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy**